# Codeigniter Welcome Page JavaScript Notifier

Tags: javascript, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get a JavaScript notification at the bottom of my Codeigniter Welcome Page using a MySQL table column named, "increment_date"

## Welcome Model

```
function increment_date(){

        $this->db->select('last_name,increment_date');
        $this->db->from('tbl_officer');
        $this->db->where('tbl_officer.status=1 and increment_date>= DATE(now()) and increment_date<=DATE_ADD(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 31 DAY)');
        $query=  $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            return $query->result();
        }
    }
```

## Welcome Controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Welcome_Model');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('dashboard');
        $this->load->view('footer');

        $this->data['noti']=$this->Welcome_Model->increment_date();


    }
}
```

URL of jquery.noty.packaged.js as mentioned in the footer.php as follows:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/notify/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.js"></script>
```

## Welcome View (Dashboard)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
    <?php

    $now = new DateTime();

    //;

    if (!empty($noti)) {
        foreach ($noti as $noti_date) {
            $date = new DateTime($noti_date->increment_date);        

            ?>
        generateNoty('warning','bottomLeft','Increment Date of <br> Officer 123 is.  <?= $noti_date->increment_date ?>;

            <?php
        }
    }

?>
    });

</script>
```

## Desired Output

An increment_date -> '2019-11-10' is available in the officer table and I want to notify this value before one month in the welcome page.

But the notification didn't notify in the page. 
What may be going wrong ? 
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stored the result of your query as `$this->data['noti']`, but you did not pass that to your view.  [The docs show how to do that](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view).

In your Controller method:

```
public function index() {

    $this->data['noti']=$this->Welcome_Model->increment_date();

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('dashboard', $this->data);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Comment: @mcode You need to pass data to your view, and this is the way. If you are still having problems, you have another problem as well.  What happens now?

Comment: @ Don't Panic. No error found. But notifier didn't work

Comment: @mcode Come on, try a little harder! :-) Debug it! In your view try `<?php var_dump($noti); ?>`.  View the generated source, is your JS code getting created correctly?  Is your JS file getting included properly?  Add some `console.log()` msgs or `alert()`s in your JS ... Debug it! :-)

Comment: When I trying, <?php var_dump($noti); ?> in my view, the following message outputs. array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#25 (2) { ["last_name"]=> string(9) "Darmadasa" ["increment_date"]=> string(10) "2019-11-10" } }

Comment: @mcode OK great, so we know your data is getting to the view. So move on to the JS - is it really included?  Is the JS in your Dashboard generated correctly?  View source to see it.  Does `alert('<php echo $noti_date->increment_date; ?>')` work?  Maybe the problem is just with the Noty library, or `generateNoty`?

Comment: @ Don't Panic. alert('<php echo $noti_date->increment_date; ?>') didn't outs any value